# How to add a column in sql as a dimension in order to be used as filter in the dashbaord report

Tags: sql, teradatasql

I have a table below:

| Date | cust_ecn | msg_type_id | msg_type_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023_01-02 | Mark | 4 | legal Information |
| 2023-01-02 | Jack | 1 | New address |
| 2023-01-02 | Jack | 2 | credit record |
| 2023-01-02 | Jack | 3 | Inquiry |
| 2023-01-02 | Linda | 2 | credit record |
| 2023-01-02 | Linda | 3 | Inquiry |

I can use query code to get count of subscription for each cust_ecn:

```
SELECT date, cust_ecn, count(distinct msg_type_id)
FROM subscription GROUP BY 1, 2
```

But due to the large volume of data in production db, I can only aggregate data by date:

`Select date, count(distinct cust_ecn) cust_cnt, sum(subscription) total_subscription`  from the relevant table

(Note: I’m not sure if ‘sum(subscription) total_subscription’  is correctly used here in the above query?)

But I also need to use msg_type_desc as dimension filter in a dashboard report. How to implement this in the query code?

### I've tried to create sql query below:

```
SELECT
    date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cust_ecn) AS cust_cnt,
    MAX(max_subscription_new_address) AS max_subscription_new_address,
    MAX(max_subscription_creditrecord AS max_subscription_creditrecord,
   MAX(max_subscription_creditrecord AS max_subscription_nquiry    
   MAX(max_subscription_LegalInformation AS max_subscription_LegalInformation FROM
 ( select 
date,
        cust_ecn,
        msg_type_desc,
        MAX(CASE WHEN msg_type_desc = 'New Address' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT msg_type_id) ELSE 0 END) AS max_subscription_new_address,
        MAX(CASE WHEN msg_type_desc = 'credit record' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT msg_type_id) ELSE 0 END) AS max_subscription_creditrecord,

      MAX(CASE WHEN msg_type_desc = 'Inquiry' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT msg_type_id) ELSE 0 END) AS max_subscription_Inquiry,

      MAX(CASE WHEN msg_type_desc = 'Legal Information ' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT msg_type_id) ELSE 0 END) AS max_subscription_LegalInformation

    FROM
        The table
    GROUP BY
        date, cust_ecn, msg_type_desc) aa

GROUP BY
    Date
```

---

I'm not sure if the query above can be used to add the dimension, msg_type_desc as filter correctly?

Thank you for any help.

--RP

Comment: Hi - please format code as code and data as tables; also can you remove the random bold and heading formatting so that your question is easier to read.